# JQuery Mobile select menu's selected option selected value

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

In my php file I have two select menus. When the first one is selected second one gets the values with jquery. It works fine in simple php file. But when pasted to a file with **JQuery mobile** a little problem occurs:
With changing the first one, values of the second one changes fine but the first one's selected option still remains.

Here is my .js file:

```
function deg(){
var id = document.getElementById("il").options[document.getElementById("il").selectedIndex].value;
var ilcx;

switch(id){
case "a":
ilcx = {"x" : "x"
}; break;
case "b":
ilcx = {"y" : "y"
}; break;
case "c":
ilcx = {"c" : "c"
}; break;

}

var $el = $("#ilcx");
$el.empty(); 
$.each(ilcx, function(key, value) {
  $el.append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value", value).text(key));
});
```

and php's part:

```
 <select name="il" id="il" onchange="deg();">
                            <option id="a" value="a">a</option>
                            <option id="b" value="b">b</option>
                            <option id="c" value="c">c</option>
  </select>
                        <select name="ilcx" id="ilcx">
                            <option id="x" value="x">x</option>
                            <option id="y" value="y">y</option>
                            <option id="z" value="z">z</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: do you want to remove the selected option from first select box?

Comment: i want to remove 2nd one's previous selected when 1st one and so 2nd's values changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx3bt/1/) with the solution

**HTML**

```
<select name="il" id="il">
    <option id="a" value="x" selected="selected">a</option>
    <option id="b" value="y">b</option>
    <option id="c" value="c">c</option>
</select>
<select name="ilcx" id="ilcx">
    <option id="x" value="x" selected="selected">x</option>
    <option id="y" value="y">y</option>
    <option id="z" value="z">z</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('change', '#il', function() { deg(this); });

function deg(obj){
    var val = obj.value,
        $el = $('#ilcx'),
        $opt = $('<option />');

    $opt.val(val).text(val).appendTo($el);
}
```

Comment: Actually i setted the first selected values of first and second select menus. And when user changes the first one, 2nd's option values changes but the previous (and initial) value remains until users selects one option from new ones.

Comment: If I understand this correctly the 2nd selectbox is completely obsolete, I think you should make it an input and change the value of that... answer updated

Comment: no there must be limited choises. so 2nd select box should exists.

Comment: Ok I think now I got it, revised the whole answer.